# Same one time login for multiple apps

Tags: android

When we login in a single google app,we are able to access all google apps with same account.We need not to separately login in each google app.How can i achieve that?

I have created three apps and I want when user login in any one of them he don't need to separately login in other apps on same device.I know about content provider but i need a better approach.

Comment: google apps use google account of the device. You can create your own account type and use it

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `AccountManager`, you can start from here: https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html. The idea is that you have a single entity in the system dedicated to your apps to store account infromation (like access token), which can only be accessed by your apps (with signature verification).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom account type first, then you have to create common activity for **logging with APP_NAME** and a service to communicate.

for more details

- [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html)
- [Example](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)